# Why 00 is a valid integer in Python?

Tags: python, integer, pattern-matching

In the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals) :

```
integer      ::=  decinteger | bininteger | octinteger | hexinteger
decinteger   ::=  nonzerodigit (["_"] digit)* | "0"+ (["_"] "0")*
bininteger   ::=  "0" ("b" | "B") (["_"] bindigit)+
octinteger   ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") (["_"] octdigit)+
hexinteger   ::=  "0" ("x" | "X") (["_"] hexdigit)+
nonzerodigit ::=  "1"..."9"
digit        ::=  "0"..."9"
bindigit     ::=  "0" | "1"
octdigit     ::=  "0"..."7"
hexdigit     ::=  digit | "a"..."f" | "A"..."F"
```

I can't get why `00` is a valid integer with those definitions? It seems a `nonzerodigit` must be the leading digit, though:

```py
>>> isinstance(00, int)
True
```

And maybe the same question: why `0` is valid?

Comment: just below the table that you copied, it says: `Note that leading zeros in a non-zero decimal number are not allowed, This is for disambiguation with C-style octal literals, which Python used before version 3.0` but in your case, the leading zero prefixes a zero decimal number, which is allowed.

Comment: Also the second section after the OR statement(`| "0"+ (["_"] "0")*`) will cover the `00` pattern

Comment: @abdul-niyas-p-m Should we not read the line as `nonzerodigit` *followed by* ...?

Comment: If that's the case it would have been written `nonzerodigit ((["_"] digit)* | "0"+ (["_"] "0")*)`(OR case would have been wrapped inside a paranethis)

Comment: Alternation has the lowest precedence in EBNF. So `nonzerodigit` is only in the first alternative.

Comment: @barmar Nevertheless, [the notation page](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html#notation) includes an example with the same syntax : `onething (another)*` and specifies : onething **followed by** a seuqence of zero or more... I interpret this as the onething is compulsory.

Comment: It is. But the `|` splits it into two alternatives. `nonzerodigit` is only compulsory in the first alternative.

Comment: And `"0"+` is compulsory in the second alternative.

Comment: So `decinteger` has two syntaxes: One for numbers starting with `0`, another for numbers *not* starting with `0`. And the latter only allows the rest of the digits to be `0`

Comment: OK now I get it! Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is that the `|` notation for alternatives has lowest precedence. So `decinteger` is split into two distinct productions:

- `nonzerodigit (["_"] digit)*`
- `"0"+ (["_"] "0")*`

The first is for numbers not starting with `0`, it allows any digits in the rest of the number. The second is for numbers starting with `0`, it only allows numbers that are all `0`. Both allow optional `_` characters to be interspersed between digits for easier reading.

So `0`, `00`, `000`, etc. are allowed as valid decimal integers by the second production. And their values are all zero.

Some EBNF documentation put alternatives on separate lines to make it easier to see the breakdown. The Python documentation has chosen this more compact format.